# Need to get file name only from location in java

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I need get company name "BLU" from this path C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\BLU.qbw

I tried like this

```
String[] temp;
        String delimiter = ".";
        temp = strCompanyFileName.split(delimiter);

         for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++){
               System.out.println(temp[i]);
         }



        String[] actualHotelCode;
        delimiter = "\\\\.";

        actualHotelCode = temp[0].split(delimiter);
        int maxlength = actualHotelCode.length -1;

        System.out.println(actualHotelCode[maxlength]);
```

that temp array become empty when i do a split, please help me out of this

Comment: Change `delimiter` to `"\\."` because it's a regular expression.

Comment: How about `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1,str.lastIndexOf('.'))`

Answer (score 1):

You may use that if you are absolutely sure that in the path `\` is used not `/`.

```
int lastSlashIndex = path.lastIndexOf('\');
int lastComaIndex = path.lastIndexOf('.');
String s = path.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, lastComaIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

File file = new File("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\BLU.qbw");
String nameWithExtension = file.getName(file);

String nameWithoutExtension= FilenameUtils.getBaseName(nameWithExtension);
```